# change color of rows in a table in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to learn HTML and CSS and I have a simple question.

How can I give each row a different color in a table? For example row 1 is red, row 2 is blue etc.

This is my HTML code:

```css
#table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse;
  collapse;
}
#table td,
#table th {
  font-size: 12x;
  border: 1px solid #4D365B;
  padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#table th {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #4D365B;
  color: #918CB5;
}
#table td {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #979BCA;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact
      <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use :nth-child(even) and :nth-child(odd)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to give every row a different color? You have a few options...

- Add a class to each row and style those.
- Use the direct sibling selector `tr + tr`
- Use `:nth-of-type`

```css
table tr {background: red;}
table tr:nth-of-type(2) {background: blue;}
table tr:nth-of-type(3) {background: green;}
table tr:nth-of-type(4) {background: yellow;}
table tr:nth-of-type(5) {background: grey;}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact
      <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try like this

```css
#table tr{background: red;}
#table tr:nth-child(2n+1){background: blue;}

#table {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:600px;
border-collapse;collapse;

#table td, #table th {
font-size:12x;
border:1px solid #4D365B;
padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;

#table th {
font-size:14px;
text-align:left;
padding-top:px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#4D365B;
color:#918CB5;

#table td {
color:#000000;
background-color:#979BCA;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
<tr><th> Company</th><th>Contact<th>Country</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using [pseudo selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) `nth-child`.

```css
#table tr:nth-child(odd){background:red}
#table tr:nth-child(even){background:blue}
```

```html
<table id="table">
<tr><th> Company</th><th>Contact<th>Country</th></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
<tr><td> 1</td><td>2<td> 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Additionally you can also add a number for a specific row #table tr:nth-child(3) in case you want to have all rows in different colors

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ff0101;
}

 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #0030ff;
}
```

```html
<table class="ex1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Month

      </th>
      <th>'94

      </th>
      <th>'95

      </th>
      <th>'96

      </th>
      <th>'97

      </th>
      <th>'98

      </th>
      <th>'99

      </th>
      <th>'00

      </th>
      <th>'01

      </th>
      <th>'02

      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jan

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>11

      </td>
      <td>11

      </td>
      <td>11

      </td>
      <td>11

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Feb

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>12

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>12

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mar

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apr

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May

      </td>
      <td>21

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>21

      </td>
      <td>22

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>21

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>19

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jun

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>23

      </td>
      <td>25

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>25

      </td>
      <td>23

      </td>
      <td>25

      </td>
      <td>23

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jul

      </td>
      <td>29

      </td>
      <td>28

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>27

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>25

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>25

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aug

      </td>
      <td>29

      </td>
      <td>28

      </td>
      <td>27

      </td>
      <td>28

      </td>
      <td>28

      </td>
      <td>27

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>28

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sep

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>23

      </td>
      <td>23

      </td>
      <td>26

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>24

      </td>
      <td>22

      </td>
      <td>21

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oct

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>22

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>22

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>19

      </td>
      <td>20

      </td>
      <td>22

      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nov

      </td>
      <td>18

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>17

      </td>
      <td>16

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dec

      </td>
      <td>15

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>14

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>10

      </td>
      <td>13

      </td>
      <td>11

      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try selecting each row through CSS. In your case:

```
table tr:first-child{background:red}    or   table tr:nth-child(1){background:red}

table tr:nth-child(2){background:blue}

table tr:nth-child(3){background:orange}

table tr:nth-child(4){background:yellow}

table tr:last-child{background:purple} or table tr:nth-child(5)
{background:purple}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below small piece of code should change the color table row.

```
 table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

th {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

Source: http://www.snoopcode.com/css/css-tables