# How can I change the styling dynamically for an entire row in React-Virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

My React-Virtualized Table receives data from the back-end.
I am comparing the data for similarities, the rows which have the most similarities should change their background to 'green' for example.

How can I achieve this?
I know how to style the table, table columns or single table cells.

But how can I change/ address the styling for an entire row?
Maybe with RowRenderer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is quite opiniated and lacks information to give a simple answer but I guess you could manage className with variables that depends on the state and state change.

Comment: More Simple Question: How can I change the background color of a row. The whole row. Not every row, just a specific one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818958/change-color-of-rows-in-a-table-in-html-and-css

Comment: thank you for the answer, what I am looking for is a dynamic solution: The server gives me diff: 1, which than turn the row color to green. all rows with diff: 2 stay the same. Only based on the data the color changes, so not with basic css selectors, instead with a given function or similiar from React-Virtualized

Comment: What if the server send the id of the collection that needs to be changed as well (or maybe an index). This way you could check for the current element and the id that comes from backend, if they match then change the bg.